# What rxjs operator emits single value when any of the source observables emit?

Tags: angular, rxjs

So like rxjs operator race but so that it doesn't stop emitting.

```
time   -> 

source1 emits 1           4

source2 emits     2            5

source3 emits        3             6

so the combined observable should emit the numbers in following sequence (1 number per emit):

              1   2  3    4    5   6
```

Comment: I'd also recommend taking a look at the operator decision tree on the rxjs doc site: https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree

Comment: this actually gave me the operator. thanks!

Comment: Curious what it was if `merge` didn’t do it for you

Comment: @kevin: i don't understand your comment. my comment above was about your link that it's actually working to find the correct operator. it resulted `merge`

Comment: ah sorry, I misread your comment to say that the accepted answer of `merge` didn't work, but my link helped you find something else that did work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `merge` operator. It takes in several observables and emits as one.

- https://rxmarbles.com/#merge
- https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge